# Want to return array of strings but when I console.writeline is printing with System.Char[]

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am trying to convert a sequence of randomly generated integers to array of strings but when I `Console.WriteLine` it outputs `System.Char[]`

```
public class Sorting
{
    public void sortLinq(Random rand)
    {
        var randomValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(_ => rand.Next(10) - 5);
            
        var csvString = new Func<IEnumerable<int>,string>(values => {
                return string.Join("," , values.Select(v => v.ToString().ToList()));
            });

        Console.WriteLine(csvString(randomValues.OrderBy(x=>x)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your usage of `var` is making it hard to tell what types you're working with here. In situations where it's not very obvious what the type is, I suggest you steer clear of using `var`.

Comment: The code returns `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.Char]`, not `char[]`.  `v.ToString().ToList()` will return a `List<char>` instead of a string. `ToList()` applies on a `string`, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `)` in the wrong spot.

```
return string.Join(",", values.Select(v => v.ToString().ToList()));
vs
return string.Join(",", values.Select(v => v.ToString()).ToList());
```

Even better remove `.ToList` completely.

```
return string.Join("," , values.Select(v => v.ToString()));
```

Having said that, there really is no need for that `Func<>`:

```
var randomValues=Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(_ => rand.Next(10) - 5)
            .OrderBy(x => x);

var s = string.Join(",", randomValues.Select( i => i.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(s);
```